# To Run Javascript Function When Shearching

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I create a Javascript function that works when anyone searches for something? I have a form like this:

```
<form>
<label for="arama" id="aramab">Skin Ara:</label>
<input id="arama" type="search" name="arama" autofocus autocomplete="on" placeholder="Örn.Notch"></input>
</form>
```

How can I do this with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Any way you could make your question a little clearer?  I am having a hard time understanding what it is that you are trying to do.  Furthermore jquery is javascript, its just a framework built on top of it.

Comment: im sorry my english bad

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a `input` event.
With jQuery it's very easy:

```
$('#arama').on("input", function(){
    console.log("bla");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/frod0qu3/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
document.getElementById("arama").onkeyup = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById("arama").value;
  console.log(input)
}
```